# problemas con laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5

Buenas tengo este problema con mi proyecto, estoy usando una navegacion dinamica para las vistas entre visitando y administrador, las momento de ejecutar el servidor de laravel la vista de visitante funciona perfectamente, pero al loguearme como administrador, se rompe la aplicacion con este error, no entiendo porque, si la vista admin ya la tengo creada. seria genial que me dieran ideas, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

hola creo que lo que te esta pasando es simplemente el metodo navigation no impreme el nombre de la vista solo lo retorna y al hacer el renderizador (imprimir) no toma el valor y solo imprime un texto vacio, es por eso que muestra `partials.navigations.` con el punto al final, no hay nada intenta imprimir la vista antes de hacer la concatenacion

Comment: gracias. como sugieres que debería ser esa linea de codigo??

Comment: puedes hacer algo como ```return print auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->role->name : 'guest';``` no es buena practica pero al menos podrias estar seguro de que la impresion es el problema. espero que ayude

Comment: Gracias. no me funciona de esa forma, tampoco.